# Two stacked HP 2900-48G switches. Now I need a couple SFP+ ports, possible?

Tags: networking, hp-procurve

I have two stacked HP 2900-48G switches in rack A.
Now in rack B I need a switch that provides at least two SFP+ ports (for two servers) and at the same time establish a 10G link to the switches in rack A.

Is that even possible? I don't know if there exists any HP switch with CX4 AND SFP+ ports.

As the 2900-48G only has 10G stacking ports I assume there is no way other than stacking it with a different model that provides SFP+ ports, right?

But I also don't know if you can stack different models?

Comment: I would send a mail to HP sales or a good local reseller.

Comment: I had a chat session with HP support but that guy told me he can't help me because 2900-48G switches are old.

Answer (score 0):

[End-of-Sale Announcement for HP ProCurve 2900-series.](http://h20564.www2.hp.com/hpsc/doc/public/display?docId=emr_na-c01743850&sp4ts.oid=3296372)

> End of Sale Date: October 1, 2009 or While Supplies Last

**It's 2015.**

While HP ProCurve switches have *lifetime* warranties, I'd suggest upgrading to a current model. Something like the [HP ProCurve 2920 series](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=5354494) is a good bet for the moment, as they have some 10GbE ports and stacking modules available. Although, if I need port density, I go to the [5400zl](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=1827663) or [5400R zl2](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/products/networking-switches/product-detail.html?oid=7074783) series.

As for CX4 connections for 10GbE, they've fallen out of favor. You won't find CX4 used many places today.

For your use case, is it even necessary to stack the switches? If so, is there anything else you can do to consolidate racks?